# How to make owned type non-nullable?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Location entity. It has a collection of opening hours and it should be stored as a JSON in the database.

```
public class Location
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OpeningHours> OpeningHours { get; set; } = new List<OpeningHours>();
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen24Hours { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeInterval> Intervals { get; set; } = new List<TimeInterval>();
}

public class TimeInterval
{
    public TimeOnly Start { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly End { get; set; }
}
```

and below is my configuration

```
internal class LocationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Location>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Location> builder)
    {

        builder.OwnsMany(
                l => l.OpeningHours, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
                    ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(o => o.Intervals);
                    ownedNavigationBuilder.WithOwner();
                });
    }
}
```

No matter what when adding new migration it makes OpeningHours nullable. I want to make it non-nullable in the database